# Fetch parameters name and values of method throwing exception

Tags: c#, exception, postsharp

I have two classes with code

```
[ExceptionAspect]
public class BaseService
{
    public void Method1(string email)
    {
        new BusinessClass().Method2(1, email, false);
    }
}

public class BusinessClass
{
    public void Method2(int count, string email, bool ignoreCase)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My exception aspect class has following code and using this code I'm able to fetch parameters name and values of the **Method1** only not of **Method2**.

```
[Serializable]
public class ExceptionAspect : OnExceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs eventArgs)
    {
        object[] args = null;
        if (eventArgs.Arguments != null)
            args = eventArgs.Arguments.ToArray();

        var parameters = eventArgs.Method.GetParameters();
    }
}
```

Now what I want is to fetch and save the method parameters name and values of the exception target site i.e. count=1,email=email and ignoreCase=false of method name Method2.

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute to the BusinessClass.

```
[ExceptionAspect]
public class BusinessClass
```